# How to set the WSL hyper-v vmswitch to external via powershell script

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm trying to set the WSL virtual switch to external via a script. It seems like I have it correct but it's giving an error. I tried the following two variations in Powershell running as administrator.

```
> Set-VMSwitch -Name WSL -SwitchType External -AllowManagementOS $true -NetAdapterName "Ethernet 2"
Set-VMSwitch: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.

> Set-VMSwitch -Name WSL -SwitchType External -AllowManagementOS $true -NetAdapterInterfaceDescription "Intel*"
Set-VMSwitch: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.
```

I have been able to create a new switch using New-VMSwitch, but if I do that, I get the following error when trying to start WSL:

```
The network was not found.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/0x803b0001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove `-SwitchType External` from the command line.
Apparently `Set-VMSwitch` is very particular. It doesn't want to be told the SwitchType, it wants it to be implied. A careful reading of the description on the [second example in Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmswitch?view=windowsserver2022-ps#examples) shows that it is the solution.

Here's a few lines that help with getting the names as well:

```
$switch = Get-VMSwitch WSL
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object Status -eq Up | Sort-Object ifIndex | Where-Object {$_.Name -NotMatch 'vEthernet' -and $_.Name -notmatch 'Network Bridge'} | Select-Object -First 1
Set-VMSwitch $switch.Name -NetAdapterName $adapter.Name
```

Note that if you're doing this for WSL as I am, this only worked for me if WSL had been started, but was terminated. The WSL virtual switch isn't created after boot until WSL is started. So, I started WSL with `wsl --exec "echo"`, terminated it `wsl --terminate`, ran the above, then started WSL again. There might be a simpler way.